# Find the first comma in the array and the total number of this symbol

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a student at tech unuversity. I have my hometask on JS.
Here it is: ***given a char array. By pressing the "Result" button, find the first comma in the array and the total number of these characters, if it is in the array, if not, display the corresponding message.***
I made my code, but the teacher said that it`s wrong, because message of number of comma must displayed one time, so as message that there is no comma. Please, help me.

```js
function result() {
  alert('PI-20\nTask №5\nArray\nOpt. №4')
  var total = 0;
  var arr = ['s', 'b', '4', '7', ',', '5', 'a', ','];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == ',') {
      total += 1;
      alert('First comma has index ' + i);
      alert('Total numaber of comma ' + total);
    } else {
      alert('There is no comma');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="result()">Result</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the answer you desired.

```
function result(){
        alert ('PI-20\nTask №5\nArray\nOpt. №4')
        var total = 0;
        var arr = ['s', 'b', '4', '7', ',', '5', 'a', ','];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == ',') {
                total += 1;    
            } 
        }
         if(total > 0){
            alert('Total numaber of comma ' + total);
            }
         else{
            alert('There is no comma');
            }
    }
```

All you have to do is to put an if condition after the end of the loop to get the final total value than check if the total value is greater than 0 if yes than alert the message that there are commas in the array.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more modern approach, using a [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to collect some aggregated values from the array and display them.

Note: It is generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers. The snippet uses [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

```js
document.addEventListener("click", handle);

const log = (...strs) => {
  console.clear();
  strs.unshift('PI-20 Task №5 Array Opt. №4');
  console.log(strs.join("\n"));
};

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement) {
    return result(document.querySelector("input").value.split(""));
  }
}

function result(inputValue) {
  if (!inputValue.length) {
    return log(`no values`);
  }
  const results = inputValue
    .reduce( (acc, val, i) =>
      ({ ...acc,
        chr: acc.chr || val,
        sumOfCommas: (acc.sumOfCommas || 0) + (val === ',' ? 1 : 0),
      }), { firstComma: inputValue.indexOf(",") } );
  log(
    `Input: "${inputValue.join(``)}"`,
    `Total characters: ${inputValue.length}`,
    `${results.firstComma > -1 ? `First comma Array index: ${
      results.firstComma} (position ${
        results.firstComma + 1} in input)` : `No comma's`}`,
    `${results.firstComma > -1 ? `Number of comma's: ${
      results.sumOfCommas}` : ``}`
  );
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="sb47,5a," placeholder="Type some text"/>
<button>Result</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

THE PROBLEM is in the var total = 0 ;

Set it as var total;

Comment: Your response might be correct, but it's hard to tell. Consider showing an updated code example would help answer their question.